# Only First Line of Function Being Executed

Tags: javascript

I have a function that gets called when my form is submitted. Depending the value of a variable, one of two functions then get called to update my Firebase Firestore. The problem I'm having is that only the first line (console.log()) for each of the other two potential functions gets executed. My console is not showing any errors.

**This gets called when submitting the form**

```
function setSpeakerInfo() {
    var nameField = document.getElementById("name");
    var nameValue = nameField.value.trim();
    if (nameValue) {
        nameField.dataset.state = 'valid';
    } else {
        nameField.dataset.state = 'invalid';
    }

    if (nameField.dataset.state == 'valid') {
        if (docId != null) {
            updateSpeaker();
        } else {
            createNewSpeaker();
        }
    } else {
        alert("You must provide a name!");
    }
}
```

**These are the two other functions that get called depending on whether docId is null or not.**

```
function updateSpeaker() {
    console.log("UPDATE");
    var docRef = db.collection("/annual meeting/speakers/Speakers").doc(docId);
    return docRef.update({
        Name: document.getElementById("name").value,
        Title: document.getElementById("title").value,
        Bio: document.getElementById("bio").value
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully updated!");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });
}

function createNewSpeaker() {
    console.log("CREATE");
    db.collection("/annual meeting/speakers/Speakers").add({
        Name: document.getElementById("name").value,
        Title: document.getElementById("title").value,
        Bio: document.getElementById("bio").value,
        Image: ""
    })
    .then(function(docRef) {
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });
}
```

**EDIT: As requested, here is my form.**

```
<form id="speakerInfo" onsubmit="setSpeakerInfo()">
    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"><br><br>
    <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Title"><br>
    <h3>Bio</h3>
    <textarea id="bio" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea><br><br>
    <h3>Image</h3>
    <input id="image" type="file" accept="image/"><br>
    <img id="profileImage" width="25%" height="25%"></img><br><br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Here is my console.**
[image]

Comment: can we see your form?

Comment: by "gets executed" I presume you mean that you're not seeing the effect of those statements, not that they're literally not being executed? If you put a breakpoint on those lines, I'm guessing they do get called - is that right?

Comment: i don't know but i think the problem is that the api your using is not set to async and is set to sync and in easier words it is maybe too slow

Comment: I'm not seeing the effect of the updates to firebase, but I've also added another console.log() statement after the first one and only the first one is executed. Nothing after it.

Comment: @DanO I've added my form to my question.

Comment: Where is docId defined? Seems like that could be the issue since the presence of that variable determines which function is called

Comment: docId is declared at the beginning of the js file and is initially null. When I retrieve existing firebase data it gets a value assigned to it. That part, and the if statement that determines which function to run seems to work fine.

Comment: You do not cancel the form submission

Comment: 1. try placing a `console.log()` at the end of the function (just to be sure nothing wrong happen with the calls.   2. check if the request to your DB has been issues, and was it replayed? (can you add Timeout to your request?)

Comment: @TomerW It did not get triggered.

Comment: The db lines are probably throwing errors that end up getting swallowed since they happen as part of an event callback

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors So what should I do to see the errors?

Comment: @raginggoat You can wrap **everything** within `updateSpeaker` and `createNewSpeaker` in a `try / catch` and `console.log` the error in the `catch` to see if anything is throwing

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors It's not showing any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. The form was reloading before the Firebase async methods could finish.